# Scrolling text within certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image of a car radio that I would like to have scrolling text inside of to mimic the way a song title would scroll on an actual car radio. I tried using a marquee but it is not responsive to phone or tablet screen sizes. How can I go about doing this? I have inserted my code below. Thanks for the help in advance.

```css
body {
    font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
    background-color: #eda4b7;
    color: #030406;
}

a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    opacity: .6;
}

p {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 10%;
}

h2 {
    padding: 0 15%;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.date{
    font-weight: 800;
    color: WHITE;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0 5% 0 6%;
    margin: 0;
}

/*-----Column stuff-----*/

.column20center {
    width: 60%;
        padding: 0 5% 0 6%;
}

.column10center {
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 10%;
}

.column10left {
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.column10right {
    width: 40%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

/*----- Hero Image -----*/

#heroimg {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#heroimg img {
    width: 100%;
}

#arthed {
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
    font-family: quantico, montserrat;
```

```html
<div id="heroimg">
           <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/snwceomedia/ohi/81dc2dc1-3763-4b8a-b061-adf9f62ecbd0.sized-1000x1000.png">
            <h1 id="arthed">
Title here</h1>
        </div>
        <p>placeholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder text</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something as like below snippet.

```css
.column10center {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.column10left {
  width: 40%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.column10right {
  width: 40%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}


/*----- Hero Image -----*/

#heroimg {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#heroimg img {
  width: 100%;
}

#arthed {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 20%;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
  font-family: quantico, montserrat;
}

.marquee {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 210%;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="heroimg">
  <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/snwceomedia/ohi/81dc2dc1-3763-4b8a-b061-adf9f62ecbd0.sized-1000x1000.png">
  <div id="arthed" class="marquee">
    <div>
      <span>Title Here</span>
      <span>Title Here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>placeholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder
  textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder textplaceholder text</p>
```

Comment: Can you show me an example within my own code? I don't know how I can implement it.